# GetTypeInfo from semantic model in Roslyn fails to find type of "var"

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following code:

```
public class ParallelLinqAsSequential
{
    private List<Customer> _orders;

    private void Method()
    {
        var query = (_orders.AsParallel().OrderBy(ord => ord.CustomerID).Select(ord => new
        {
            Date = ord.OrderDate
        })).AsSequential().Take(5);
    }

    private class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID;
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was expecting that when calling the semantic model over the variable named "query" it would be able to infer it as an Enumerable of anonymous type with a field of "DateTime" type. But it fails and shows ErrorType.

While in Visual Studio you can see it as in the image below.

[image]

The code I am using to get this from the Roslyn is:

```
public void GetType(SyntaxTree tree)
{
            var Mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("RoslynVar", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });


            VariableDeclarationSyntax variable = ... // get the relevant variable
            TypeInfo symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variable.Type);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code used to do this?

Comment: Check the diagnostics on your semantic model. Maybe you're missing a reference to System.Core

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the semantic info for the `query` variable, not the `var` (`TypeSyntax` you get from `variable.Type`) part of the `var query` declaration. In your case this would be:

```
var typeSymbol =
    ((ILocalSymbol)semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable.Variables[0])).Type;
```

You get the `ITypeSymbol` which the usaful part of `TypeInfo`.

Alternatively, you can get a more specific `ITypeSymbol` from the `VariableDeclaratorSyntax.Initializer`, which is the part after `var query =`:

```
var typeSymbol =
    semanticModel.GetOperation(variable.Variables[0].Initializer.Value).Type;
```